# Everyone is from Godric's Hollow?

Tags: harry-potter

From this blog post: http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/05/harry-potter-movie-marathon-highlights/

They mention this:

> Everyone is from Godric’s Hollow (which Harry didn’t know). It is
>   apparently the source of all wizarding families.

I didn't quite get that. Can someone explain? I realize that they're probably just making fun of the movie, but well, I still don't see how did they come to that conclusion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From HP Wiki's entry on [Godric's Hollow](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Godric%27s_Hollow) here are some people of note that have lived there:

- The Potters
- The Dumbledores
- Godric Gryffindor
- Bowman Wright
- Bathilda Bagshot
- Ignotus Peverell

It also mentions that

> it has been home to many wizards and witches of note

So, the quote you reference is clearly a tongue-in-cheek exaggeration referencing just how many important characters seem to trace back to this one town.

Answer (score 8):

Not everyone in *Harry Potter* is from Godric's Hollow. Whoever wrote that is just plain wrong. Many of the wizards and witches in the series are from places other than Godric's Hollow.

The Malfoys are from Wiltshire. The Weasleys are from Ottery St. Catchpole. Harry himself is raised in Surrey, although he was indeed born in Godric's Hollow. Dean Thomas (Gryffindor) is from West Ham. The Lovegoods live quite near the Weasleys. Sirius Black's home, No. 12 Grimmauld Place, was in London. Snape was from Spinner's End. Professor McGonagall is from the Scottish Highlands (Pottermore). Hagrid is presumably from the Forest of Dean, as JKR has stated she gave him a Forest of Dean accent. Tom Riddle/Voldemort was raised in a Muggle London orphanage with his ancestry in Little Hangleton. These are just off the top of my head. Beauxbatons students were from France. Durmstrang students were from northern Europe (some say Bulgaria). The Quidditch World Cup had wizards and witches attend from many many countries, including the United States.

The Ministry of Magic, St. Mungo's Hospital for Magical Maladies, Diagon Alley, and The Leaky Cauldron are all located in London, which might suggest the London metropolitan area is the heart of the wizarding world in Britain.

After the International Statute of Secrecy was adopted in 1692, Pottermore talks about Hogwarts students "from all over Britain" finding discreet ways to get to Hogwarts without being seen. So not everyone could have come from Godric's Hollow.

I agree with **Phantom42** -- whoever wrote that was probably being sarcastic, like, "Everyone and their dog is from Godric's Hollow."

Comment: Whoever wrote that being me. And yes, it was meant as a joke.