# Where were Hufflepuff, Ravenclaw & Slytherin from?

Tags: harry-potter

Inspired by [rand al'thor's question asking us to narrow down the location of Gryffindor's birthplace](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117110/where-is-godrics-hollow), I thought I'd ask about the other three.

Where were Helga Hufflepuff, Rowena Ravenclaw and Salazar Slytherin born? (The more precision the better.)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The Sorting Hat gives us some clues, along with some portraits at *The Wizarding World of Harry Potter* (which has questionable canon status – I’m not sure if JK Rowling was directly consulted on the details).

What we have is also rather vague – nothing as specific as Godric’s Hollow has survived to the present day. And unlike Gryffindor, we only know that these three grew up in a vaguely defined region – we don’t know exactly where, and we don’t know whether they were born somewhere else entirely.

- **Helga Hufflepuff came from Wales.**

  In Harry’s fourth year, the Sorting Hat refers to her as:

  > Sweet Hufflepuff, from valley broad,

  Within the UK, "the valleys" is commonly associated with Wales.

  Further, according to her [HP Wikia article](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Helga_Hufflepuff#cite_note-0):

  > At *The Wizarding World of Harry Potter*, Helga Hufflepuff speaks in a Welsh accent in her portrait on the Forbidden Journey Ride.
- **Rowena Ravenclaw came from Scotland.**

  Likewise, the Sorting Hat’s song:

  > Fair Ravenclaw, from glen,

  The word [“glen”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glen) is usually associated with the Scottish valleys. This is further backed up (again from [the HP Wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Rowena_Ravenclaw#cite_note-scotland-0)) by this claim:

  > In *The Wizarding World of Harry Potter*, Ravenclaw's portrait speaks with a strong Scottish accent.
- **Salazar Slytherin came from somewhere in east England.**

  The Sorting Hat’s song:

  > Shrewd Slytherin, from fen

  This could be referring to [the Fens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fens), an area of marshland that cover a large stretch of eastern England. But fens are also a natural habitat for certain types of snake – this may be telling us nothing more than his affinity with serpentine creatures.

Comment: Drat, I missed the Wales part! Not sure how strong the evidence there is though - there are plenty of valleys all over Britain (the Yorkshire Dales spring to mind too).

Comment: @randal'thor Yeah, I’m clutching at straws, but also throw in the Welsh accent on the portrait :-)

Comment: How canonical is the *Wizarding World of HP*? I don't know much about it, but like you, used it as a source from HP Wikia ;-)

Comment: JKR has apparently been very focused on the details of the theme park area, and I think she would give her opinion on this sort of thing, like how she vetoed certain film points.

Comment: @randal'thor The Dales may have valleys in the physical geography sense, but most British people I know associate "the valleys" as South Wales. There are also plenty of fens outside of The Fens.

Comment: I'm from Yorkshire, and no one would refer to the Yorkshire Dales as "the valleys". They'd simply say "the Dales". "The valleys" is absolutely a colloquialism for Wales.

Comment: @monkjack Agree the Valley's is definitely how Wales is referred to in the UK, the Dales are called the Dales.

Comment: it might also be worth saying in the Film The Deathly Hallows - Part 2 Helena Ravenclaw speaks with a Scottish accent too being played by the lovely Kelly MacDonald. If the daughter is Scottish the mum might well be too especially with the clue from the poem

Comment: @Cearon O'Flynn - I agree Ravenclaw was Scottish but don't remember Helena having a Scottish accent in the film? On a different note, I believe JKR has said Ravenclaw chose the location for Hogwarts. It being in Scotland may mean more evidence to support this idea.

Comment: @ThruGog your right just watched it! I think in my memory I must have put Merida's voice over it! Whoops

Comment: @Cearon O'Flynn - Ha, easily done!

Answer (score 10):

Taking a quote from [ibid's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/117123/31394):

> A thousand years or more ago,
>   When I was newly sewn,
>   There lived four wizards of renown,
>   Whose names are still well known:
>   Bold Gryffindor, from wild moor,
>   Fair Ravenclaw, from glen,
>   Sweet Hufflepuff, from valley broad,
>   Shrewd Slytherin, from fen.
>
> <sub>-- *HP and the Goblet of Fire*, Chapter 12</sub>

So we can deduce a few things:

- Rowena Ravenclaw came from "glen", presumably a reference to the glens of **Scotland**. (This is backed up by the fact that in *The Wizarding World of Harry Potter*, Ravenclaw's portrait speaks with a Scottish accent.)
- Salazar Slytherin came from "fen", which could well refer to [the Fens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fens), a region of **eastern England**.
- Helga Hufflepuff came from a "valley", which is far too generic a description: **unknown**.